# Custom group in characters viewer

Tags: macos, git, emoji

I am trying to start with [Gitmoji](http://gitmoji.carloscuesta.me) and so far it takes me some time to find the appropriate emoji in the Characters viewer on macOS. Is it possible to define custom group of characters? There is already Emoji, Arrows, Bullets/Stars. I am looking for a way how to add my own. I am not interested into workarounds like using Favorites group

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use each of the gitmoji emoji a bunch of times and then they will be in your frequently used list in the Emoji & Symbols picker.

The categories/groups are defined by Unicode as ranges of the character set. I am not aware that it is possible to define your own. There are no clues in `CharacterPicker.framework`.

You could also setup keyboard text replacements so you can type `:apple:` and it will be automatically replaced with . I use [Alfred](https://www.alfredapp.com/) to do this, but you could use *System Preferences > Keyboard > Text* to do it.

You could also try [Dash](https://kapeli.com/dash), a document viewer/browser, that can be configured to show a Gitmoji cheat sheet. I have assigned a custom keyboard shortcut for Dash to appear.

[image]